# Multilingual website in React version 18?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, google-translate, i18next, react-i18next

I am facing issue while doing internalization and localization for my WebApp which is build on React version 18 using Material UI for styling..

I found i18next, react-i18next, i18next-intl, i18next-n and related libraries for doing this functionality in react web applications.

But these all libraries are including to write manually files of .json for each language I want to give support for different regions...

But My admin has lot of component including in it So how can I able to give add manually translation for all the content of my web application which has complete dashboard.

There is Google Translate API which I am using in my test app for translating whole content of specific web page which is not viable solution of it...

I am open to to your suggestions, findings, relevant technical docs - Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://youtu.be/VfxBpSXarlU?t=27

Comment: Yes, but this is the manual method of doing this which is way too long. I want some library which itself do this by using built in function and methods.

Comment: for simples websites there is https://github.com/i18next/i18nextify or https://github.com/locize/locizify, but for React webapps you need to instrument your code...